# rails: render a template into a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get my templates rendered and the html/json saved in variables in some actions in my application. Something like:

```
def show
  @var = Var.find(params[:id])
  x = render "tmeplate1", format: :json

  render nothing: true
end
```

When I call this actions I get an error: `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in VarsController#show`

any other way I can use the templates and not rendering twice ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have written **render** two times in the method that why double render error comes. Use `render_to_string`

```
x = render_to_string "tmeplate1", format: :json
```